# Problem passing external parameters to XML File Data Adapter

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have problems trying to generate a report using a "XML File" Data adapter (remote SOAP WS) that uses some external parameters as input data.

I have defined the external parameters "NOMBRE" and "APELLIDO" but when I try to add them to the POST message body (free text) with "$P{NOMBRE}" and "$P{APELLIDO}" it doesn't replace the placeholders with the actual values of the parameters.

This is the XML Source of the "XML File" data adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xmlDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterImpl"><name>prueba_imagenes</name><dataFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="httpDataLocation"><method>POST</method><url>http://myendpoint.com/myendpoint.php</url><username></username><password></password><body>&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ecr="urn:http://myendpoint.com/myendpoint.php"&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
   &lt;soapenv:Header/&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
   &lt;soapenv:Body&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
      &lt;ecr:peticion_JD3 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
         &lt;nombre xsi:type="xsd:string"&gt;$P{NOMBRE}&lt;/nombre&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
         &lt;apellidos xsi:type="xsd:string"&gt;$P{APELLIDOS}&lt;/apellidos&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
         &lt;edad xsi:type="xsd:string"&gt;3&lt;/edad&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
      &lt;/ecr:peticion_JD3&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
   &lt;/soapenv:Body&gt;&#xd;&#xd;
&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;&#xd;
</body><header><name>SOAPAction</name><value>"urn:http://myendpoint.com/myendpoint.php#peticion_JD3"</value></header><header><name>Content-Type</name><value>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</value></header></dataFile><useConnection>true</useConnection><namespaceAware>false</namespaceAware><selectExpression></selectExpression><locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">es_ES</locale><timeZone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">Europe/Paris</timeZone></xmlDataAdapter>
```

Exactly the same WORKS if I use the WebService Data Adapter plugin but doesn't work with the native "XML File" Data Adapter.

What am I doing wrong?